# vba error 13 type missmatch, VBA

Tags: vba, excel, mismatch

New to using VBA and know little about it. Using it for an Engineering project to solve deep seated slope stability problems. When entering in the first 7 calculations VBA solves these correctly in a user form. But when I try to calculate the 8th formula (AVHS8) it gives me an error, witch is run time error "13" type mismatch. I am unsure what the problem is, the formulas work in excel perfectly. if anyone could help it would be much appreciated. The problem is below.

BES = 2.5 RAD = 18.58 DTCP = 7.5 and OH =17, these are just numbers that are set and do not change

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()
RAD = Sqr(DTCP ^ 2 + OH ^ 2)
BES = DTCP / 3
AVHS1 = (0)
AVHS2 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP - BES) ^ 2) - OH)
AVHS3 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP - BES - BES) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES))
AVHS4 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP - BES - BES - BES) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 2))
AVHS5 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP - BES - BES) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 3))
AVHS6 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP - BES) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 4))
AVHS7 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 5))
'VBA can solve all the above code. it cant solve the code below (AVHS8)
AVHS8 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (DTCP + BES) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 6))
```

Comment: What types are the variables declared as? your sample values yield AVHS8 ==7.31540576925892 for me when doubles

Comment: Sounds like a `Dim` problem. None of the variables you have used are declared in your code. So, VBA makes a decision for you and declares the variables for you. OH (for example) is assigned 17 and might be declared as an `Integer`. Yet, Integer would not suffice to hold any of the intermediary results from the last calculation. Try to `Dim` all variables as `Double` (just to test this theory) and try again.

Comment: @Ralph without explicit declarations, they are `Variant` types. The type of the `Variant` for `OH` will be VT_I4 initially but will become VT_R8 if it becomes fractional.

Comment: You serious about using 3.14 for pi?! You *must* be an engineer. Consider using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()`

Comment: is (DTCP+BES)^2 larger thand RAD^2?  ie are you trying to take the sqr of a negative number?

Comment: I just ran the most on this and you are not taking the sqr of a negative.

Comment: I also believe there is a RADIANS and DEGREES function in VBA.  if not there is definitely one excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume those are controls on your form rather than variables, which would explain the problem. As controls, the contents are text and when you use `(DTCP + BES)` that is actually returning `7.52.5` rather than 10, because `+` will also work as a concatenation operator. Change the last line to:

```
AVHS8 = (Sqr(RAD ^ 2 - (CDbl(DTCP) + CDbl(BES)) ^ 2) - (OH) + (Tan(30 * 3.14 / 180) * BES * 6))
```

Comment: That is dang annoying, you can use -, /, *, etc. but as soon as you pop in the + it all goes to pot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Leverage()

Dim i As Long
Dim counter_less As Long
Dim count_pos As Long

Dim row_count As Long
Dim num As Variant

num = InputBox("Enter threshold")


row_count = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2

counter_pos = 0
counter_less = 0

For i = 1 To row_count

If Abs(Cells(i + 2, 3)) > num And Cells(i + 3, 3) <> "" Then

counter_less = counter_less + 1
        If Cells(i + 3, 3) < 0 And i Then
            counter_pos = counter_pos + 1
   End If
   End If
   Next
counter_pos = counter_pos / (counter_less)
counter_less = counter_less / row_count
MsgBox counter_pos & " %"`enter code here`
End Sub

I get error 6: Overflow. Anyone has any suggestions?
```